# multiple polymorphic associations for a model

Tags: laravel-4, polymorphic-associations

Is it possible to have many-to-many polymorphic associations where both sides of the pivot are polymorphic?

I am looking to use this in my tagging system.

There are things that are 'taggable' such as `Articles` and `Images`. And there are things that are 'taggers' like a `User` or `Event`. So for example an `Article` is written and it is tagged with `User` Joe Smith and `Event` 2014 Kid's Camp.

My ideal table structure would be

```
Tags

id
taggable_id
taggable_type
tagger_id
taggable_type
```

As far as I can tell Laravel doesn't have a default way to handle this association. Their many-to-many polymorphic example has a tagging system, but the tag names are more static.

Is there a good way to do this or a good way to hack it?

Comment: You can do it, but it's like many-to-many between 3 models. There's no builtin method for this and you need some tweaks to make it work. You can read this to help you start https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot